# How to get a decent wordpress setup using a linode VPS or other hosting solution?

Tags: hosting, wordpress

I am currently running Wordpress on a linode 512 VPS. The setup is as follows: nginx, php-fpm and wordpress. The blog seems to be getting slower loads and I've recently lost the ability to install plugins or upload photos.

Would it be a better solution to simply host the blog on wordpress.com or some other wordpress hosting service and avoid all the maintenance required?

Or maybe simply code up my own blogging tool in some python framework where I have complete control of the the blog?

Edit:
I was actually able to fix the plugin problem by simply changing the owner of the wordpress dir to that of what nginx uses.

Comment: do you want to provide more information on your current setup os etc

Answer (score 1):

It's better first to understand why is it becoming slower? Maybe you've just misconfigured something like your database or php-fpm www pool size. Have you looked into performance metrics?

Checking output of utilities like `top`, `htop`, `vmstat`, `iostat`, `sar` can be a good start here.

Comment: I have a lot of links to youtube videos, which I tried to reduce the load of by installing a plugin to show snapshots instead of loading the actual videos.

Comment: loading the snapshots is probably adding more load to your server - that kind of plugin is designed to speed up page load speed not server load

Comment: The problem can be not related to videos. We still need more info to determine a bottleneck, after that we'll be able to suggest you how to solve that.

Comment: Embedded YouTube videos don't put any load on your server, at all. All the load is on YouTube's servers.